# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select ID No...' to data type int

Tags: c#

I want to fill my combobox with my database columns, which are int and primary key.

```
 private void cmbxIDno_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetTextBoxes();

        SqlCommand SelectedID = new SqlCommand();
        SelectedID.Connection = clsINIReader.nConn;

        SelectedID.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tools  WHERE ID= '" + cmbxIDno.SelectedItem.ToString()+ "' ";


        SqlDataReader drID = SelectedID.ExecuteReader();

        while (drID.Read())   //Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select ID No...' to data type int.
        {
            txtPN.Text = drID["PartNumber"].ToString();
            txtNomenclature.Text = drID["Nomenclature"].ToString();
            txtSerial.Text = drID["SerialNo"].ToString();
            txtShelfNo.Text = drID["ShelfNumber"].ToString();
            txtTSnumber.Text = drID["TSnumber"].ToString();
            txtBinNumber.Text = drID["BinNumber"].ToString();
            txtRentalPrize.Text = drID["RentalPrize"].ToString();
            txtCurrency.Text = drID["Currency"].ToString();
            txtQuantity.Text = drID["Quantity"].ToString();
            txtCalibrDateInfo.Text = drID["CalibrationDate"].ToString().Replace("00:00:00", "");
            txtCalibrationPeriod.Text = drID["CalibrationPeriod"].ToString();
            txtCertfNumber.Text = drID["CertificateNo"].ToString();
            textBox11.Text = drID["CertificationPath"].ToString();
            txtIDno.Text = drID["ID"].ToString();
        }
        drID.Close();
    }
```

but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Select ID No...' to data type int

Comment: Where is your database call?

Comment: The combobox doesn't know about your database. You have to run your query against the database and get a result back, then you can put data from the result in the combobox.

Comment: What does `cmbxIDno.SelectedItem` contain? From the error message it seems like it contains SQL code. Besides, you should use a parameterised query instead of concatenating in the value in the query.

Comment: When you populate the combo? and did you came accross [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about your problem I'm just guessing, but the most likely problem is that your combo box does have what you think it has.

A simple step-through debugging session would confirm this quickly enough but my guess is that your combo box `SelectedItem` value contains something like 'SELECT Id FROM ...', and does not contain an actual integer. For example, you may have incorrectly tried to populate your combo box with ID values but got something completely different.

If that's true, if you inspect the value of `SelectedID.CommandText` immediately after you set it, you'll see that it says something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tools  WHERE ID= 'SELECT Id FROM ...'
```

Assuming your ID value is actually an integer (in which case, why you put the quotes I'm not sure), you will get an error that "SELECT Id FROM ..." is not an integer.

From there, you just need to figure out why your combo box has the wrong data in it...

---

On a side note:

If you **have not** already done this step-through debugging process, that really should have been your very first step, long before you came here to ask about it. That's the kind of thing that's likely to merit you a lot of downvotes and not many good answer.

If you **have,** that would be useful information to include in your question so that others don't jump to the same conclusion I did and decide your question isn't worth answering.

Answer (score 0):

Learn reading error messages. The message clearly states that your ID is a varchar value and you try to convert it to an integer.

Might be that the conversion doesn't work because within the combo box it does not parse the string to int and/or your data contains string values within the ID column which cannot be converted to int.

Cannot give you more details because your question is just way to vague.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I ran into the same issue here, where one of the field in table is declared as INT and it is nullable.  When one of the record has this int value set as null, while(reader.read()) will raise this exception: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.".....

I am still working on figuring out a proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if(cmbxIDno.SelectedItem!=null)
{
    SelectedID.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tools  WHERE ID= '" +  Int32.Parse(cmbxIDno.SelectedItem.ToString())+ "' ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            string str = "select empFirstName from tbl_employeeEntry where empId = ' " +Convert.ToInt32 (cmbEmployeeIDNew.Text) + "' ";//here the value for this combobox is int type in database. thats why i converted into integer.
            SqlDataReader sdr = DataClass.ReteriveRecordsViaDataReader(str);
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string name = (string)sdr["empFirstName"]; // name is string value
                txtEmployeeNameNew.Text = name;
            }
```